# Can't change color of button image

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

When I write this code:

```
self.button.imageView.image setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:76/255.0 green:145/255.0 blue:65/255.0 alpha:1]];
```

I get error

> No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'setTintColor:'

But for another image it worked! What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImage class doesn't have the tintColor property.
You can set the tintColor on the UIImageView or on the UIButton, but the final result can vary according to your configuration of the button.